# INSTR equivalent into c# string.indexof() how do i use

Tags: c#, oracle

I have if else condition in one function in oracle 
i need to convert that into c# code please help.

```sql
IF INSTR( pString, pSeparator, -1, 1) != ( LENGTH( RTRIM( pString )) - LENGTH( pSeparator ) + 1 )
THEN
   -- There isn't one at the end so add it
   l_Return                     := pString || pSeparator;

   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Did not find seperator - ADDING');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can use [`string.EndsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) instead, that's exactly what you are trying to check:

```
if(!pString.EndsWith(pSeparator))
{
    //There isn't one at the end so add it
}
```

Comment: +1 Wow!!! All that code... In this!

Comment: But technically he is checking the negative. `!EndsWith`

Comment: @xanatos: That's right, I fixed the sample

Comment: what about this code 
l_Return                     := pString || pSeparator;
i tried all are string how do i do (||)?

Comment: @ashuthinks: Assuming this just adds to the string (I'm not familiar with the syntax) you can just do `pString = pString + pSeparator;`

Comment: for this too :(
   l_SearchString_FinPos        := INSTR( l_Return, pSeparator, 1, l_SearchString_CurrentPos );

Comment: something like `l_SearchString_FinPos = l_Return.IndexOf(pSeparator, l_SearchString_CurrentPos)` - change the variable names to .NET conventions though.